# How to handle user authentication state in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm having this very strange behaviour with firebase and flutter.

My goal is show a screen when the users are logged in, and a different one where they can sign in.

See my main function below

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      allowFontScaling: false,
      builder: () => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        ),
        home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
                    ? StartupPage()
                    : AppHome();
              }
              return Text("");
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The login screen:

```
class LoginPage extends HookWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _emailController =
        useTextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue.empty);
    final _passwordController =
        useTextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue.empty);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFA46EE2),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/LOGO.png",
              height: 60.h,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Form(
              key: _key,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Welcome back!",
                    style: primaryHeadline,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: CustomTextField(
                      hintText: "Email",
                      secured: false,
                      isEmail: false,
                      onSave: (data) {},
                      onValidate: (value) => validator(value, "Email"),
                      controller: _emailController,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: CustomTextField(
                      hintText: "Password",
                      secured: true,
                      isEmail: false,
                      onSave: (data) {},
                      onValidate: (value) => validator(value, "Password"),
                      controller: _passwordController,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: _emailController.text,
                          password: _passwordController.text,
                        );

                        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                        //   MaterialPageRoute(
                        //     fullscreenDialog: true,
                        //     builder: (context) => AppHome(),
                        //   ),
                        // );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40.h,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: defaultBackgroundColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(defaultRadius)),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        'Log in',
                        style: defaultWhiteText,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The register screen

```
class RegisterPage extends HookWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _emailController =
        useTextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue.empty);
    final _passwordController =
        useTextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue.empty);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF5EFFC),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/ELEMENT_02.png",
              height: 60.h,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Form(
              key: _key,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: CustomTextField(
                      hintText: "Email",
                      secured: false,
                      isEmail: false,
                      onSave: (data) {},
                      onValidate: (value) => validator(value, "Email"),
                      controller: _emailController,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: CustomTextField(
                      hintText: "Password",
                      secured: true,
                      isEmail: false,
                      onSave: (data) {},
                      onValidate: (value) => validator(value, "Password"),
                      controller: _passwordController,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                        await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: _emailController.text,
                          password: _passwordController.text,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40.h,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: defaultBackgroundColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(defaultRadius)),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        'Signup now',
                        style: defaultWhiteText,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm having this behaviour:

- when I register with email and password, then sign out, the StartupPage is displayed as expected.
- When I sign in,  then sign out, the AppHome is not displayed.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The code you shared seems fine. The `userChanges()` should fire the same in both bullet points, but it's hard to be certain without seeing the code that handles the sign-up/sign-in.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I edited the question and added both screens. I realized I was calling Navigator to navigate manually to the AppHome after logging in or registering, so I removed the call to let the root component to handle the screen switch. Now nothing happens at all after signing in or registering.

Comment: hmmm... I don't see what's going on, but the amount of code is getting a bit much. Can you reproduce this without using any UI? For example, just sign in from your `main` method, or the constructor of your main widget, and then `listen` to `FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges()` to see if it fires. If that doesn't fire when you sign in/sign out, it's definitely on the Firebase side. But if the stream fires on sing in/sign out, the problem must be in the UI flow somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you signOut, `currentUser` becomes `null`.

```
 FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
                    ? StartupPage()
                    : AppHome();
```

This will return `StartupPage()` after signing out.
So your code is working fine I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I edited the question and added both screens. I realized I was calling Navigator to navigate manually to the AppHome after logging in or registering, so I removed the call to let the root component to handle the screen switch. Now nothing happens at all after signing in or registering.